# In a Windows batch file, does double '@' in @@echo off mean something else than @echo off?

Tags: batch-file

I'm seeing double `@` being used in some of our batch files, as in `@@echo off`, and as far as I can see the initial first `@` is redundant and I want to remove it to only have `@echo off`.

Can I safely do that or does it have some hidden meaning I don't know about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` has the effect to suppress the repetition of the executed commands, including the command `echo off/on` and `cmd` does not care how many times it is used:

The effect of:

```
@echo off
ping localhost
ping google
echo test string
```

is exactly the same as:

```
@@@@@@@@echo off
ping localhost
ping google
echo test string
```

and

```
@ping localhost
@ping google
@echo test string
```

or even:

```
@(ping localhost
ping google
echo test string
)
```

so technically `@@somecommand` simply suppresses repetition, then suppresses repetition even though it has no effect any longer as it was already suppressed.

So a single `@` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

One or more `@` disables the echoing of the current command.
If the echo mode is already OFF, then the `@` has no special effect anymore.

So to answer your question, yes you can remove the redundant `@`, one is enough.